# How to write the regex in Python to maintain the group content unchanged?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use python to run regex to do the replacement like below:

```
a = "%I'm a sentence.|"
re.sub(r"%(.*?)\|", "<\1>", a)
```

Then `b = <\1>`, but I want to get the result of `<I'm a sentences.>`

How am I supposed to achieve this? I tried to group `I'm a sentence`, but I feel I did something wrong, so the result doesn't maintain the group 1.
If you have any ideas, please let me know. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: As always with regex, use raw string literals: `r"<\1>"`

Comment: Thank you @Rawing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a raw string for the replacement, otherwise `\1` will be interpreted as an octal character code, not a back-reference.

And assign the result to `b`.

```
b = re.sub(r"%(.*?)\|", r"<\1>", a)
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/2nSEea)

Comment: Thanks, @barmar! This helped a lot!

Answer (score 3):

to capture group use `\g<1>`

```
a = "%I'm a sentence.|"
a = re.sub(r"%(.*?)\|", "<\g<1>>", a)
# <I'm a sentence.>
```